# how many unary operators in C language

Tags: c

In `C99`, `6.5.3 Unary operators`:

```
Syntax
1 unary-expression:
postfix-expression
++ unary-expression
-- unary-expression
unary-operator cast-expression
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
unary-operator: one of
& * + - ~ !
```

This says that unary-operator is one of `&`, `*`, `+`, `-`, `~`, `!`, so I think that `++`, `--` and `sizeof` are not a unary operators, are they?

Comment: 42?..................

Comment: The `sizeof` operator takes only a single expression, so it's definitely unary. The same for every other operator, "unary" means that it takes a single operand, "binary" that it takes two operands.

Comment: From the [Wikipedia articel on "unary"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation): "In mathematics, a unary operation is an operation with only one operand, i.e. a single input." It's the same in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linguistically the phrase `unary-operator: one of & * + - ~ !` means that they are unary operators, but not necessarily the only unary operators. If the phrase is instead interpreted mathematically one might think they are the only unary operators.

The title of the chapter is "Unary Operators" which indicates that the first interpretation is the correct one. `++`, `--`, casts, and `sizeof` are also unary operators.

Comment: but in msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0c1cfax.aspx.           It does not say casts is also unary operators?

Comment: Is the language defined by Microsoft or by the standard? The MS page is not entirely stringent.
On that page it says there are three types of operators, unary, binary and ternary. Yet, on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy30xyk.aspx they say that casts are operators too. Casts have one operand so by definition they are unary.